# How to find the difference in time between two date/time columns from a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below,

```
S.no          f_req_time         f_drop_time
1    2016-07-11 06:04:00   2016-07-11 06:44:00
2    2016-07-11 12:20:00   2016-07-11 13:10:00
3    2016-07-11 16:19:00   2016-07-11 17:25:00
4    2016-07-12 09:03:00   2016-07-12 09:58:00
5    2016-07-12 12:10:00   2016-07-12 12:49:00
```

I want to add a column called wait time, this will be the difference in time of the 1st value of column 'f_drop_time'(2016-07-11 06:44:00) i.e the first value of S.no.1 and the second value i.e from S.no.2 of 'f_req_time'(2016-07-11 12:20:00 ).How can I make a column of all the differences of time.I tried a for loop.it returns all null.

the date-time column is in POSIXct format

my code,

```
funtion<-for (i in 1:nrow(driver_27)) {
  driver_27$wait <- driver_27$f_drop_time[i+1]-driver_27$f_req_time[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take the `lead` of the first column and use `difftime` to do the subtraction (Note that it is not clear about the `unit`)

```
driver_27$wait <- with(driver_27, as.numeric(difftime(c(f_req_time[-1], NA),
                     f_drop_time, unit = 'hour')))
driver_27$wait
#[1]  5.60000  3.15000 15.63333  2.20000       NA
```

#### data

```
driver_27 <- structure(list(S.no = 1:5, f_req_time = structure(c(1468231440, 
1468254000, 1468268340, 1468328580, 1468339800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), f_drop_time = structure(c(1468233840, 
1468257000, 1468272300, 1468331880, 1468342140), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("S.no", "f_req_time", "f_drop_time"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ,but the results are not as expected..I need the expected results as following, like the first wait time should be difftime('2016-07-11 21:50:00', '2016-07-11 16:14:00') which is
Time difference of 5.6 hours,however it shows 7.1 hours..the second wait time should be difftime('2016-07-12 01:49:00','2016-07-11 22:40:00') Time difference of 3.15 hours however it is 5 hrs is seen.and so on.Plz suggest

Comment: @hariharans  It is based on the example you provided.  Here the unit is `min`, change it to `hour`

Comment: yes i understood that ,i mean the calculated value seem to to be incorrect.The o/p resulted from you code is 7.1,5,17.6,3.7,NA hrs.However the expected o/ps are 5.6,3.15,15.6,2.2,NA hrs

Comment: @hariharans  If you check the data in my post the first f_req_time is `2016-07-11 06:04:00` and the second `f_drop_time` as `2016-07-11 13:10:00`.  You can check `difftime(driver_27$f_drop_time[2], driver_27$f_req_time[1], unit = 'hour')
Time difference of 7.1 hours
> 13.1 - 6.04
[1] 7.06`

Comment: thanks for patiently answering me.i used this command and it gave me the expected results, driver_27$wait<-sapply(1:5, function(i) difftime(time1 = driver_27$f_req_time[i+1], time2 = driver_27$f_drop_time[i], units = "hours"))

Comment: @hariharans  Okay, now i understand why you got different values.  It is the lead of the f_req_time that you wanted.  I updated the code

Comment: Thanks,i keep getting confused when to use apply function and when not to.you have provided a solution without using an sapply() or a loop..I suppose that will be a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

This solution offsets `f_drop_time` and stores in a new column to facilitate validation/checking. It also uses `lubridate::interval()` to calculate wait time in hours:

```
# data
data.frame(
  f_req_time = c("2016-07-11 06:04:00" , "2016-07-11 12:20:00", "2016-07-11 16:19:00", "2016-07-12 09:03:00", "2016-07-12 12:10:00"),
  f_drop_time = c("2016-07-11 06:44:00", "2016-07-11 13:10:00", "2016-07-11 17:25:00", "2016-07-12 09:58:00", "2016-07-12 12:49:00"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> x

# create a new column that has ofset f_drop_time by 1
x %>% mutate(temp = c(f_drop_time[-1], NA)) -> x

# convert to lubridate format
ymd_hms(x$temp) -> x$temp
ymd_hms(x$f_drop_time) -> x$f_drop_time

# calculates the interval in hours in 'wait_time' column
(x %>% mutate(wait_time = interval(f_drop_time, temp)/hours(1)) -> x)

# removes temp
x[, !names(x) %in% c("temp")] -> x
```

produces (with temporary data):

```
           f_req_time         f_drop_time                temp wait_time
1 2016-07-11 06:04:00 2016-07-11 06:44:00 2016-07-11 13:10:00  6.433333
2 2016-07-11 12:20:00 2016-07-11 13:10:00 2016-07-11 17:25:00  4.250000
3 2016-07-11 16:19:00 2016-07-11 17:25:00 2016-07-12 09:58:00 16.550000
4 2016-07-12 09:03:00 2016-07-12 09:58:00 2016-07-12 12:49:00  2.850000
5 2016-07-12 12:10:00 2016-07-12 12:49:00                <NA>        NA
```